# How to capture image of Youtube Video and display on web site

Tags: video, youtube, screenshot, video-capture

I am interested in creating a website that displays a few "screen captures" on the screen. These "screen captures" can be any image file type (ex: jpeg, png, etc.) I would like to be able to display the first frame screen capture of a Youtube Video. When the user clicks on this, the user will be redirected to the Youtube URL.

How can I retrieve the screen shot or first frame image of a Youtube video, given it's URL? For example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbcmYbMB9mo Using this, I'd like to have an image of the GoPro camera. Is there an API to capture the first image of the Youtube Video?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **YouTube IFrame API** (see https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Here is an example for playing the video provided in your question (`gbcmYbMB9mo`):

```
<body onload="LoadYouTubeIframeAPI()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var player = null;
        var playerParams =
        {
            playerVars:
            {
                "enablejsapi":1,
                "origin":document.domain,
                "rel":0
            },
            events:
            {
                "onReady":onPlayerReady,
                "onError":onPlayerError,
                "onStateChange":onPlayerStateChange
            }
        };
        function LoadYouTubeIframeAPI()
        {
            var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
            scriptElement.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptElement = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            firstScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement,firstScriptElement);
        }
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
        {
            player = new YT.Player("player",playerParams);
        }
        function onPlayerReady(event)
        {
            player.loadVideoById("gbcmYbMB9mo");
        }
        function onPlayerError(event)
        {
            ...
        }
        function onPlayerStateChange(event)
        {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

You might need to "play a little" with this code in order to prevent the video from starting automatically...

Comment: Thanks for this information barak. I have two questions. 1) Is there a way to simply capture the image of the video and display it on the website without embedding the video/player into the website? 2) If I choose to embed the video on the site, how can I use more than one video?

Comment: You're welcome. Please see https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference.

Comment: I've went over the api, but does it really have anything built in to capture images? I can't find anything.

Comment: I see no reason why this answer is accepted.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the video is likely a different `origin` to where the code is running (your website), it can't be done. A direct video embed can take screenshots with the canvas API.

For youtube and other iframe methods, you'll need serverside processing. Libs exist for this, such as: https://github.com/jsgilberto/youtube-frames