# How to Capture youtube video as image which is been played in iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api

I am using Youtube API and playing a video from youtube by sending video ID.
and video is been played well.

Code:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
```

Now i have a button and i want the javascript to capture the frame which is been played at that particular time.

```
<input type="button" id="capture" value="Capture" onclick="Captureimage();"/>
```

like we have this screen capture in VLC media player
I want to have the same functionality here.

Since its an embedded media(Video inside iFrame), struggling bit.

tried with html2canvas. No lucks.

Can anyone plz help.

Regards,
Arun

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture image of Youtube Video and display on web site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918326/how-to-capture-image-of-youtube-video-and-display-on-web-site)

Comment: thanks for the response. but the question remains the same for me as well the for him.i.e., : "Is there a way to simply capture the image of the video and display it on the website without embedding the video/player into the website? "

Comment: Hi there. Can you please suggest on this. I feel its not duplicate. So please look into the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, Arun

Comment: The linked question has accepted answer only by a mistake. In fact there is no answer.