# Getting keyframe thumbnails from YouTube IFrame API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm working with the [YouTube IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to create a video embed with buttons that start the video at various times.

After working with the [`seekTo()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#seekTo) function, I was wondering if it was possible to grab an image from any given frame in the video.

For example, say I wanted to get an image from the frame at 1 minute 30 seconds into the video, is there anything in the API that will help me retrieve it?

Comment: You could try something like the answer posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21918625/4241842).